# What is the Lagrangian tori?

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

I am looking for the definition of lagrangian tori for symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$ ?

Comment: "Tori" is the plural for "torus".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching through the literature suggests (see e.g. M. Audin, Torus actions on symplectic manifolds, 2004, p. [89](http://books.google.co.nz/books?id=uKXO9BDsk_kC&pg=PA89&lpg=PA89)) that a Lagrangian torus is a submanifold which is (diffeomorphic to) the torus $\mathbb{T}^n \equiv \mathbb{S}^1 \times \dots \times \mathbb{S}^1$ and is a [Lagrangian submanifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_manifold) at the same time.